# Separate sign in Java

Tags: java, function, delimiter, separator

I'm new in Java and I have a question. I have a function `isSeparator(String stroke){...}` how can I show this delimiter? Please help me. Thanks.

This is my code:

```
 class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println(isSeparator("Hello, world!"));//true
         System.out.println(isSeparator("Hello world!"));//true Why?
     }
     public static boolean isSeparator(String stroke) {
         StringBuilder SEPATORS = new StringBuilder(",. \\t!\\\";:'-");
         char ch=',';
         for(int i=0; i<stroke.length(); i++) {
            ch = stroke.charAt(i);
            for(int j=0; j<SEPATORS.length(); j++) {
                if(SEPATORS.charAt(j) == ch) {
                   return true;
                }
            }
         }
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Don't know what you're trying to do, but `SEPATORS` includes both space and exclamation mark, and `"Hello world!"` contains a space, so method returns `true`, just as you told it to do.

Comment: Why are you double-escaping the separator characters? `",. \\t!\\\";:'-"` means `,`, `.`, *space*, ``\``, `t`, `!`, ``\``, `"`, `;`, `:`, `'`, and `-`. You've included ``\`` twice. I think you meant to use `",. \t!\";:'-"`, where ``\`` and `t` are not included, but *tab* character is.

Comment: Why is the name `isSeparator` while the functionality is `hasSeparator`?

Answer (score 0):

Why put the separators in a StringBuilder? Just make a static String that includes all of the separators, and then use

```
for ( int i=0; i < stroke.length(); i++ ) {
   if (SEPARATORS.indexOf(stroke.charAt(i)) >= 0) ) {
      return true;
   }
}
return false;
```